# What do the Core Data Generated Accessors for an NSOrderedSet look like?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, accessor, nsorderedset

I have a `NSManagedObject` subclass (Parent) that has an ordered to-many relationship with another `NSManagedObject` subclass (Child). I require Parent to use KVO to watch a value on the Child(ren) held in its `NSOrderedSet`. This means I need to manually add and remove the Parent as an observer when a Child is added-to or removed-from the set. This means I need to implement my own accessors for the `NSOrderedSet`.

Where can I see what these accessors should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Observe the collection as a whole and allow the OS to handle observation for each child.  Observe the keypath to the property from the vantage point of the parent.  In other words, the parent will be observing itself via a keypath which goes though the children.

```
[self addObserver: self forKeyPath: @"childs.observedProperty" options: ... context: ...];
```